# When  a quasifibration is a Hurewicz fibration?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In studying quasifibration I have a question.

When  a quasifibration $F\to E\to B$ is a Hurewicz fibration?

If $F,E$ and $B$ are CW-complex, it is right?

Comment: Having CW complexes is certainly not enough.  A "classical" example of a quasifibration that is not a Hurewicz fibration is the projection of an L-shape onto an interval, so that the fiber over one endpoint is an interval and the fiber over all other points is a point.  All of these spaces are CW-complexes.

Comment: @Mike: you've provided a valid answer. Why don't you post it as one?